# How can I input password in advance with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

I often operat my remote vps.I write some script to simply my work.But every time after the line of ssh command,I have to input the password manually.How can I provide the password in the script and so that it will work on automatically,though I know it is not safe but my aim is just for convience.
I have tried many ways.
To be detailed,if I have a vps with the configuration as flows:

> Protocol=SSH
>
> Host=122.122.122.122
>
> Port=22
>
> UserName:root
>
> Password:mypassword

I will write a script as flowers to connect the vps:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -p 22  root@122.122.122.122
#Other command flowers
```

Then I run the script.Before other command runs,I have to type the password.

> root@122.122.122.122's password:

So I wonder if I have any solution to avoid typing password manually.

Comment: google for "passwordless ssh". there's plenty of docs on how to set up keyfiles for automatic login.

Comment: This is off-topic and shows zero research effort. Please make an attempt to understand the site rules before asking a question.

Comment: Can you configure the SSH server to allow private keys?  Then you can create a keypair, save the private key as `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, register the public key with your server, and never have to enter a password again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method 1:
 first Create a new keypair:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Copy the public key to the server:

```
ssh-copy-id user@my.server.com
```

now server should recognize your key  hence wont ask you for the password anymore:

```
ssh user@my.server.com
```

method 2:

use expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Method 1 works.However , I cannot understand method 2.Although I copy the code to localhost and modefy it,it doesn't work.Can you recommend me some material if I want to learn something about 'expect' .